# Read binary blob field in R from an sqlite database

Tags: r, sqlite, blob

I would like to read a binary field from an sqlite database from R.

I succeeded with an indirect method, consisting in first exporting the binary field in a temporary file, via a shell command invoking sqlite3 and then reading this binary file with the readbin() command. Here is the detailed code:

```
library(RSQLite)
fileConn<-file("script.sql")
writeLines(c('.load fileio.dll','SELECT writefile("tmp.bin",Curve) FROM Table1 WHERE Id=41;','.exit'), fileConn)
close(fileConn)

shell('sqlite3.exe database.sqlite < script.sql')

to.read<-file(description="tmp.bin","rb")
tmp<-readBin(to.read,"integer",n=10000,size=2)
plot(tmp)
close(to.read)
```

I want to directly read the binary field with R, without creating a temporary file via sqlite3.

According to suggestions (thanks a lot for that !), I tried the following:

```
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(),dbname="database.sqlite")
tmp<-dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT quote(Curve) FROM Table1 WHERE Id=41")
tmp
```

which retruns:

```
quote(Curve)
1             '\023'
```

It doesn't looks good, as I am supposed to get a vector of 870 integer elements, starting with :

```
head(good)
[1] 19 19  0 19 19 19
```

What's going wrong with my sql statement ? How can I directly read the binary field with R ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You could just `base::unlink` the file afterwards?

Comment: What's not working for you with `dbGetQuery(con,'SELECT`... ?

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the solution in [How to write binary data into SQLite with R DBI's dbWriteTable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20547956/11654), you can convert the blob into a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) with the [quote() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#quote).
That is, execute a query like

```sql
SELECT quote(Curve) FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 41
```

and the result is a string in the form

```
X'1234ABCD....'
```

You would then have to convert the hex digits back into binary data.

Comment: "You would then have to convert the hex digits back into binary data."

How would you go about doing that in R?

Comment: The answer to the linked question shows how to convert the hex representation to raw bytes.

Comment: I've read the linked answer several times but still cannot tell which part is doing the actual conversion. Would you be able to point it out, or list a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, I struggled with this today and was successful with the following:

```
blob2string <- function(blob){
  hex_raw <- wkb::hex2raw(blob)
  rawToChar(as.raw(unlist(hex_raw)))
}
```